# Proof by Induction for $n! > n2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For all natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge6$. Prove by induction that $n! > n2^n$. I proved the base step by showing that $n=6$ and that $720>384$. Then I assumed that $n=k$. Then for the third step I wanted to prove $n=k+1$ so I ended up with 
$(k+1)! \gt (k+1)2^{k+1}$. I'm not too sure how to continue on with the proof from here.

Comment: You have a typo in your title+question: $n 2^2$ should be $n 2^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(k+1)! = (k+1)k!$. Now apply the induction hypothesis to the $k!$ term, together with the fact that $k>2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n \geq 6$ is such that $n! > n2^{n}$, then
$(n+1)! > (n+1)n2^{n} > (n+1)2\cdot 2^{n} = (n+1)2^{n+1}$.